# How to resize a STL list pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

If I declare a STL list as

```
list<int> mylist;
```

then it's easy to resize it by just using mylist.resize()
But the problem is I have declared a list pointer as

```
list<int> *mylistptr=new list<int>[n];
```

Now I want to change the size of mylistpr. Since it is a pointer, therefore compiler is throwing error in case of using resize() with it. There is an option of allocating memory for mylistptr using malloc() and then use realloc() to resize it. But, what if I don't want to use malloc() and realloc(). is there any other way ????

Thanks

Comment: `list<int> *mylistptr=new list<int>[n];` Why would one ever do that?

Comment: Resizing a pointer doesn't mean anything in C++ because you can't resize pointers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen , Actually I want to have a list in which each element will be holding a list corresponding to it. or a sort of two dimensional list. As for as your question is concern, why would one ever do that ??........ I am using it for adjacency representation of graph.

Comment: @juanchopanza,  when we allocate memory for 1D or 2D array using malloc() then the variable holding the allocated memory seems like pointer but we can use that as array and can resize as well. As I mentioned above that I am trying to make two dimensional list............

Comment: That's very nice, but the fact remains that you can't resize a pointer. What you describe is making it point to a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done simply the following way

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> myLists( n );

//...

myLists.resize( new_n );
```

Comment: thanks .............
It worked and I tried 

     std::vector<std::vector<int>> mylist(n);

it's working too